# sed: replace immediate next word coming after a particular keyword

Tags: regex, sed, github-actions, command-line-interface

In GitHub actions, when merging a push request to main, I would like to replace the branch name occurrence in a notebook by `main`.

For instance, given the below line:
`git clone --branch fork1 https://somrepo.git`

Using the below regex, all values till the end of the line are replaced, however, my intention is to simply replace `fork1` by `main`:

`sed -i 's/\(--branch\)\(.*\)/\1 main/'`

Another example, given the below line:
`"https://colab.research.google.com/github/user/repo/blob/fork2/notebook.ipynb"`

Using the below regex, all values till the end of the line are replaced, however, my intention is to simply replace `fork2/` by `main/`:

`sed -i 's/\(blob\/\)\(.*\)/\1 main\//'`

**EDIT:**

To clarify my question, my github action use case is to replace the branch name by `main` in several files after merging a PR..And no, `GITHUB_REF_NAME` would not work in this case since the ref_name would point to the merge branch and not the initial branch where PR was created.

```
name: Update Branch Name

    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
    
    jobs:
      restore_main_branch_name:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        
        steps:
        - name: Checkout code
          uses: actions/checkout@v4
          
        - name: Update .ipynb files
          run: |
            sed -i "s|${{ github.ref_name }}|main|g" colabLaunchScript.ipynb
    
            
        - name: Commit changes
          run: |
            git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
            git config --local user.name "GitHub Actions"
            git commit -am "Restore main branch name in .ipynb file"
            git push -u origin main
```

Comment: Looks like you want `[^ ]*` instead of `.*` in the first case, and perhaps simply `s%/fork1/%/main/%` in the second.

Comment: Probably don't use `-i` until you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, [**not repro**](https://ideone.com/jFhucb).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your link shows a different (but much better) pattern than the OP has in their question.

Comment: @tripleee It is the only way to show. We can't expect to get a modified string if we ask to replace `a` if there is no `a` in the input string. There is no `fork1/` in the input provided. So, 1) either the user made a typo, or 2) the user is not showing us what they are really using. So, my example shows there is no problem if the string to search for is actually inside the input. And is valid to show this question is off-topic.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Please include your GHA workflow in your question. Currently, it sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Apparently, using [`GITHUB_REF_NAME`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) should automatically give you the current branch name which you can use wherever needed. Please add all the details in your question along with the occurrences where you need to replace it. Thanks!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is how I understand their question. https://ideone.com/wrSKBZ

Comment: @tripleee so the first problem was solved indeed as you suggested..I was using `[^ ]*` without a space before it but `fork1` was kept and `main` added before it as shown here: https://ideone.com/fuCijY
I tried to reproduce Problem 2 with the same logic but it failed.

Comment: Because you removed a space where I had one. `/\(--branch\)\([^ ]*\)/` looks for `--branch` immediately followed by non-space characters. Conversely, in problem 2, you are looking for a space where there is none.

Comment: @tripleee i see..so I removed space for problem 2 but everything after `blob/` was replaced by `main/` and not only `fork2/` please advise https://ideone.com/bXzmAE

Comment: Why are you not simply using the solutions I already provided, or reading up on what these expressions mean if you really want to understand them?

Comment: in the solution you provided you simply replaced fork2 by main but this is a variable and I cannot hardcod it like this. thank you for your positive tone! @tripleee

Comment: So you want to match characters which are not spaces _or slashes;_ `[^ /]*`

Comment: Pardon my frustration; this is almost certainly a duplicate but you seem to be moving the goalposts down here in the comments. Thanks for editing your question to clarify it.

Comment: Going forward, please focus on one question per post.

Comment: no worries..thank you @tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the next non-space token after `--branch`, match `--branch` followed by one or more spaces, followed by the longest sequence of non-space characters.

```
sed 's/\(--branch  *\)[^ ]*/\1main/'
```

(If you have `sed -E` this can be simplified to

```
sed -E 's/(--branch +)[^ ]*/\1main/'
```

but this is a non-POSIX extension.)

Your attempt had `.*` which simply matches all characters up until the end of the line (i.e. any character `.` repeated as many times as possible `*`).

To match the next non-space, non-slash token after `/blob/`, match non-space, non-slash characters `[^ /]` as many as possible `*`; and probably use a different delimiter than slash to simplify things for yourself;

```
sed 's%\(/blob/\)[^ /]*%\1main%'
```

If you need the replacement string to come from a shell variable, you need to use double quotes instead of singne ones; this then requires you to use more backslashes in places where the shell will eat some of them. A simple workaround is to use a single-quoted string next to a double-quoted string so you don't need to add a boatload of backslashes;

```
sed 's%\(/blob/\)[^ /]*%\1'"$branch%"
```

The [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) has answers to common beginner questions and links to learning materials.

Comment: I will be using this solution for now..
while looking forward for @Azeem suggestions using GHA Default environment variables

Answer (score 1):

First case: match whitespaces, followed by a sequence of non-whitespaces. replace the non-whitespaces with `main`

```
s/\(--branch\)\s\+\(\S\+\)/\1 main/
```

As pointed out by user tripleee, `\s` and `\S` may not be supported by your version of sed. Alternatively you can use:

```
s/\(--branch\)[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)/\1 main/
```

Second case: replace `/fork1/` with `/main/`:

```
s#/fork1/#/main/#
```

Note: the chosen subsitution delimiter in this case is `#` instead the usually preferred `/`, so that `/` does not have to be escaped.

Comment: Perl shorthands like `\s` and `\S` are not portable; they work in some `sed`s but not in others.

Comment: @tripleee Fair point, thank you. I added an alternative version that makes use of `[:space:]` instead